# Paypal preapproved payments, doesnt show price?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am playing around with the PHP adaptive payments library, trying to set up preapproved payments. This is for an ordering system where the order is made, and money not taken until its confirmed it can be fulfilled.

I think I have it all working nicely, but I just noticed, when it forwards you to paypal to actually pay, no where does it say the actual amount you are approving for paypal to take.

There is definitely an amount being passed, as on the various scripts that send and receive payment data, it is definitely shown in the debugging output. To me this seems like a huge flaw in the system, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, didnt spot this in the documentation...

displayMaxTotalAmount

```
xs:boolean

(Optional) Whether to display the maximum total amount of this preapproval. It is one of the following values:

    TRUE – Display the amount

    FALSE – Do not display the amount (default)
```

Comment: This shows in the second screen, after having logged in.
Did you find a way to show the sum before logging in?
This is very bad UX in my opinion.

Comment: nope, I think it will only show it after logged in. agreed not great, but thats paypal for you :(